# <identifier> expected

Tags: android

i make first steps with android. but i get this error: identifier expeted at "`puplic void try(View view)`". where is the error?

```
   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.View;
   import android.widget.EditText;

   public class MainActivity extends Activity
   {
       /** Called when the activity is first created. */
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
       }

       puplic void try(View view) 
       {
           String wert;
           EditText F1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.b1);
           wert = F1.getText().toString();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

try is reserved word in java, use something else

```
 public void try2(View view)
```